# Is it possible to edit the "pick a new color" values in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors, email-client

In Outlook I'm a fan of the "Pick a new color when replying or forwarding" option, as each reply getting its own color helps me with tracking/rereading complex conversations.

The one thing I don't like is the pool of colors it uses -- some aren't very readable, and others don't carry a professional look. Is there a way (via editing registry keys or otherwise) to customize the pool of colors Outlook uses for this?

The feature in question is pointed out below:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it seems these are hardcoded in Outlook and not configured anywhere externally.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Out of curiosity, how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer! I have been looking for something along these lines for a while as one of the colours you get assigned at some point is bright pink. I tried searching on the RGB and hex value for one of the colours but nothing showed up in the registry. I guess there's a chance that somewhere you can change them, but others have asked across the web as well and I've not spotted a solution yet.